# Domain Name hosted by GoDaddy not resolved to IIS website

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, asp.net, a-record

The goal is to get our domain name pointing to the public IP address of a VM hosting a web application using IIS7.

I have a IIS7 server running on a VM hosted by iLand.  The server has a public IP address with port 80 open.  I can hit the IP address from a browser (XXX.xxx.xxx.xx) and it gives me the default IIS website.

GoDaddy hosts our domain in question and I have mapped an A record to the public IP Address of the VM.

The IIS web application bindings are as follows

- Type: http
- Host Name: domainname.com
- Port: 80
- IP Address: *

Doing a quick DNS lookup it does look like optimalops.com is mapped to the correct IP Address.  But I still cannot get to optimalops.com domain name via a browser.

Am I missing something?  I can hit the public ip address of the server using a browser so there is some DNS setting that is not configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you wait for the TTL to expire? It appears your TTL on these DNS records is 1 hour, so until an hour has passed, your local DNS server will use the old cached entry.

Your web site is working fine, as far as I can tell, if it has something to do with task management and audit control. But I'd probably remove that "blah blah blah"...

Speaking of which, you might just have the old site in your browser cache.

Comment: I am actually still seeing the old site without the blah blah blah... Actually the old site was just cached in my browser. Thank You.  I see the new site now.

Comment: Remember to mark the question as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer that resolved your problem.